# Cover background size on React component from a Link

Tags: css, reactjs

Im having a issue trying to apply a background to a component, fullsize to the viewport using cover. However since the component itself is only the size of the content inside it, it will not fill the entire background. I believe this is due to using Router.

I would use the root to apply the background however that would apply it to the entire website including the home page.

This is how it looks - [image: Component]

And this is the mockup from figma that im trying to achieve.

[image: Figma Mockup]

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Navbar />

          <Switch>
            <Route
              exact
              path="/"
              render={(props) => (
                <Fragment>
                  <Search />
                  <Categories />
                </Fragment>
              )}
            />
            <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route exact path="/characters" component={Characters} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

**Character Component**

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="charactersWrapper">
        <div>
          <h1>Test</h1>
          <p>Test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**App.css class**

```
.charactersWrapper {
  background: url('images/luke_res.png') no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Basically you need a "content" container that takes up view height - header height to set the background on. There are many ways to achieve this. Is this a background for the entire app or just for a specific route?

Comment: Just trying to achieve it for the specific page, each page will represent a character